# Overiding Height in Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to workout how i can override a height value that I have showing for one of my classes:

```
#leftcol {
  height:295px;
  border-right: 1px solid #222427;
  margin-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Now I have written some media queries but for some reason the text within this class is going over my footer but when I switch the height off in firebug this shows up as its supposed to. Now I am trying to workout how I can overide the height value as showing it as `height:0` will not work.

Would appreciate some advice on this thanks.

Comment: give it to `!important`

Comment: I think you are asking for `height: auto` - that is equivalent to "turning height off" in the dev tools.

Comment: And where's the rest of the code?

Comment: !important doesn't fit here and it won't change anything, this can be easily done with media queries if you know what to do.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, height: auto did the trick and the !important is not being used here.